# Pandas Dataframe Duplicate row and then delete original

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'date': ['2022-07-12 00:00:00', '2022-10-25 00:00:00', '2022-04-07 00:00:00'],
    'desc': ['Southwest', 'CntyTax', 'Chef le rey'],
    'amount': [1024.32,17521.50, 93.49],
    'category': ['Vacation', 'PropTax', 'Dinner']
})
```

I want to take the "amount" for "PropTax", apply a 60-40 split to that ""amount, such that instead of having that original one row I have 2 rows that replace it. But with the same "date" and "desc" values as the original row.
But for those new rows one will have the "amount" of 60% of the original "amount" field with the category "PropTax1". The other new row will have the "amount" of 40% of that original "amount" field with the category "PropTax2".

My thought is:

1. copy the original PropTax row into two separate dataframes dfPropTax1 and dfPropTax2.
2. Update the amount field and category in each respective dataframe.
3. Then drop the original row from the original dataframe.
4. Lastly append original dataframe with each of the separate.

I can't seem to do this. It seems really easy. I've tried many variations. Please help.

```
# Here's my last version of my attempt. The latest I'm not able to update the value and getting Nan
dft = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'date': ['2022-07-12 00:00:00', '2022-10-25 00:00:00', '2022-04-07 00:00:00'],
    'desc': ['Southwest', 'CntyTax', 'Chef le rey'],
    'amount': [1024.32,17521.50, 93.49],
    'category': ['Vacation', 'PropTax', 'Dinner']
})

print(dft)
print('(Rows, Cols)', dft.shape)

PropTaxTotal = dft.amount[dft.category.isin(['PropTax'])]
PropTax1 = PropTaxTotal * 0.55
PropTax2 = PropTaxTotal * 0.45
print("PropTax1: ", PropTax1, "PropTax2: ", PropTax2)

print("-----Create row copy in new DF")
# Create row copy in new DF
dfPropTax1 = dft.loc[dft['category']=='PropTax'].head(1)
dfPropTax2 = dft.loc[dft['category']=='PropTax'].head(1)
print(dfPropTax1)
print('(Rows, Cols)', dfPropTax1.shape)
print(dfPropTax2)

print("-----Update values appropriatly")
# Update values appropriatly
dfPropTax1.loc[1, ['amount']]
print("Update")
dfPropTax1.loc[1, ['amount']] = PropTax1
dfPropTax2.loc[1, ['amount']] = PropTax2

print(dfPropTax1)
print('(Rows, Cols)', dfPropTax1.shape)
print(dfPropTax2)

# drop original PropTax
dft = dft.drop(dft[dft.category.isin(['PropTax'])].index)
print(dft)
print('(Rows, Cols)', dft.shape)

# Append new rows
dft = dft.append(dfPropTax1,ignore_index=True)
dft = dft.append(dfPropTax2,ignore_index=True)
print(dft)
print('(Rows, Cols)', dft.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lh = df.loc[df['category']=='PropTax'].values.tolist()[0]
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [lh[0], lh[1], lh[2]*.6, f'{lh[3]}1']
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [lh[0], lh[1], lh[2]*.4, f'{lh[3]}2']
df = df.drop(1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for my late reply.